# How to distribute an es6 package with submodules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to publish a package on npm. I'm not sure how to phrase what I am trying to do..maybe packaging "sub modules"?

The abbreviated directory structure is:

```
- package.json
- src/
  - a.js
  - b.js
- dist/
  - a.js
  - b.js
```

My build script uses Babel to transpile to the `dist` directory with the same modules as in `src/`. I would like
consumers to import functions from the `a.js` module like so:

```
import {foo} from "mypackage/a";
```

not

```
import {foo} from "mypackage/dist/a";
```

If I add an `index.js` to `mypackage/` and export `a` I can do

```
import {a} from "mypackage"
```

but that's not what I want...

What is the standard way to publish packages so "sub modules" can be imported like this or can someone point me to a repo that does this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, there should be two options that you can choose.

First, let me try to explain how Node sub-modules with a slash are handled by Node.
When you import the module with a slash, Node will try to look in the root folder for a file with the name that is specified after the slash. In your case, it will be `a.js`. In case nothing is found, Node will try to look for the directory named `a` containing the file `index.js`. If no file is found, nothing is imported.

So back to your problem, you can either create file `a.js` in your root folder containing the following export:

```js
export * from './dist/a';
// The traditional export should look like this, in case I have wrong ES6 export
module.exports = require('./dist/a')
```

or change the structure of your project a bit, so files `a` and `b` are located in their specific directories.

For example:

```
- package.json
- src/
  - a.js
  - b.js
- a/
  - index.js
- b/
  - index.js
```